# 1>How does one create a hotspot on Ubuntu Touch ? 2> use a VPN...?

Tags: vpn, wireless-access-point, tethering

As per the title....has anyone achieved this yet? It seems that it is difficult to custom config anything on the touch unless you change over to read/write....but then you are cutting off OTA updates....kind of a vicious circle.... as turning OTA back on after changing config ...will probably overwrite changes on next image update.....hmmm....

And next point ...VPN's not supported out of the box?  It seems that two pretty much core functions are not supported.

Any tips/hacks/ideas....welcome..

Thanks in advance.

Alex
Touch Nexus 4 Devel-prop - latest 
ubuntu 14:10 Sony Vaio

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for a wireless hotspot on the Ubuntu phone images yet. Nor is there support for VPNs. Both will be available at some point in a future over-the-air update.

In the meantime, it should be possible to use the phone for USB tethering, by running `android-gadget-service enable rndis` in the Terminal app on the phone, or via *adb*.

For VPN, you could possibly install the *OpenVPN* packages under your home directory on the phone, and manually enable/disable the VPN via the terminal, as there is no UI for it yet.

Comment: That doesn't work, it just returns rndis unknown on the BQ Auaris. It's annoying because tethering is pretty basic and standard feature that you'd expect Ubuntu to support right from the off, at the very least from an Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Sorry, that does work but it is 'android-gadget-service enable rndis' to disable it is 'android-gadget-service enable mtp'. Still, you'd think that there would be a way to do this GUI.

Comment: As I said, a future update will provide a way to enable wifi sharing, and possibly USB as well. The problem with the current rndis feature is that you either get MTP or RNDIS, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for the info, if you happen to have an idea, when this is due out, please let us know when you spot it. thanks for info on VPN.